Slight differences in output from glm weights and survey package
I observed slight differences in the parameter estimates when fitting a model with different specifications for the sample weights. One one hand I specified the weights in glm on the other I used survey package. While the point estimates were similar across both methods, the confidence intervals and p-values varied significantly. What could account for these discrepancies? Note: I used tbl_regression and tbl_merge from the gtsummary to present the estimate nicely.
library(survey)
library(gtsummary) 
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2024)
survey_data <- tibble(
  "outcome" = factor(rbinom(500, 1, 0.30), labels = c("Yes", "No")),
  "weight" = abs(rnorm(500, 6.9, 3)),
  "gender" = factor(rbinom(500, 1, 0.48), labels = c("Male", "Female")),
  "marrital_status" = factor(rbinom(500, 1, 0.31), labels = c("Married", "Single")),
  "education" = factor(rbinom(500, 2, 0.24), labels = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")))


# Unweighted --------------------------------------------------------------

mod1 <- glm(outcome ~ gender+marrital_status+education, family = "binomial", data =survey_data  )
summary(mod1) 
mod1 <- mod1 |> tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) |> bold_p()


# Specify weights in glm  -----------------------------------------------------

mod2 <- glm(outcome ~ gender+marrital_status+education, weights = weight,
            family = "binomial", data =survey_data  )
summary(mod2)
mod2 <- mod2 |> tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) |> bold_p()


# Survey design  ----------------------------------------------------------

svy_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, weights = ~weight, data = survey_data)
mod3 <- svyglm(outcome ~ gender+marrital_status+education, 
               design = svy_design, family = "binomial")
summary(mod3)
mod3 <- mod3 |> tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) |> bold_p()


tbl_merge(
  tbls = list(mod1, mod2, mod3),
  tab_spanner = c("**Unweighted**","**Weighted (glm)**", "**Weighted (survey package)**"))


